# "ssh" proxy command equivalent in Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, openssh

I am trying all possible ways to connect to SFTP server --

For this code

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/Users/roth/.ssh/id_rsa", password="XXXX")
```

I get

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Could not deserialize key data.
```

If I do the following

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname="128.xx.xx.xx", username="roth", passphrase="roth", password="XXXX", key_filename="/Users/roth/.ssh/id_rsa")
```

I get

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 128.xx.xx.xx
```

I cannot tell why since I can connect using Terminal to SFTP either by using key + passphrase or just password:

```
ssh -vvv 

OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/roth/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/roth/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/roth/.ssh/config line 8: Applying options for 128.30.*
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W 128.xx.xx.xx:22 jump.xxx.xxx.edu
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/roth/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Executing proxy command: exec ssh -W 128.xx.xx.xx:22 jump.xxx.xxx.edu

Your `ssh` connects using a jump proxy server (aka SSH tunnel).

To implement a jump server in JSch, see the [official `JumpHosts.java` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/JumpHosts.java.html).

---

*Btw, there are better ways to connect via jump server in recent versions of OpenSSH than using "proxy command". See [How can I download a file from a host I can only SSH to through another host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537319/119732#537328)*